# memory error when using setLocale

Tags: llvm, setlocale

In order to print unicode characters with llvm, I used setLocale in llvm ir:

```
call i8* @setlocale(i32 6, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([1 x i8]* @pe, i32 0, i32 0)) nounwind
```

where @pe is defined as follows:

```
@pe = private unnamed_addr constant [1 x i8] zeroinitializer, align 1
```

However, I got the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./test/bin/executable: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08f93140 ***
```

I used gdb to debug the program and the backtrace is as follows:

```
#0  0xb7728424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb74aee71 in raise () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0xb74b234e in abort () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb74e5577 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0xb74ef961 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0xb74f128b in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0xb74f441d in free () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0xb74a6730 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#8  0xb74a5299 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#9  0xb74a4cd1 in setlocale () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
...
```

How can I resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated